# What would be the result of taking the square root of this inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Here is the inequality:

$(x+3)^2\leq(y+3)^2$

I'm not sure what the result would be if I took the square root of both sides. I think that in this case:

$(x+3)^2=(y+3)^2$

it would be:

$(x+3)=\pm(y+3)^2$

But I am not sure what the result would be with the inequality. An explanation as well as an answer would be appreciated (so I can work with square/square root inequalities in the future).

Comment: It would be $|x+3|\le|y+3|$.

Comment: thanks for the comment; would you mind posting an answer with an explanation as well?

Comment: Will do; it’ll take a few minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general fact is that $a^2\le b^2$ if and only if $|a|\le|b|$, so in this case you get $|x+3|\le|y+3|$. The reason is straightforward: $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$ for any $a\in\Bbb R$. If $a\ge 0$, we have $\sqrt{a^2}=a$, and if $a<0$ we have $\sqrt{a^2}=-a=|a|$.

However, this is not how I would approach the original inequality. That inequality can be rearranged as

$$(y+3)^2-(x+3)^2\ge 0\;,$$

which after factoring the lefthand side becomes

$$\big((y+3)+(x+3)\big)\big((y+3)-(x+3)\big)\ge 0\;,$$

or

$$(y+x+6)(y-x)\ge 0\;.$$

This is true if any one of the following four conditions is met:

- $y-x=0$;
- $y+x+6=0$;
- $y-x$ and $y+x+6$ are both positive;
- $y-x$ and $y+x+6$ are both negative.

Can you solve these four cases to get the complete solution?

Comment: @guest: The third case gives you $x<y$ and $-6<x+y$; if $x<y$ is equivalent to $2x<x+y$, so if $x<y$, then $-6<x+y$ if and only if $-6\le 2x$, i.e., $-3\le x$. The full solution in this case is therefore $-3\le x<y$. The fourth case is also consistent. We need $y+x<-6$ and $y<x$. The inequality $y<x$ is equivalent to $y+x<2x$, so if we can get $2x\le-6$ with $y<x$, we’ll have $y+x<-6$. This happens when $y<x\le-3$.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the square root of both sides of your inequality, we get
$$|x+3|\le|y+3|$$
which leads to
$$-|y+3|-3\le x\le|y+3|-3,$$
or 
$$|y+3|\ge|x+3|$$
which leads to 
$$y\ge|x+3|-3\;\cup\;y\le-|x+3|-3.$$